# Window Edit Control Not Displaying

Tags: windows, winapi

Here is my code. I'm trying to create an edit control. It's not showing, however. Can some take a look at my code and point out the errors please. I can't figure out where the error is. I feel It might have something to do with the parent child relationship.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#define MAINWINDOW_CLASS_ID 140;
const char* MAINWINDOW_CLASS_NAME = "Main Window";
const char* TEXTAREA_CLASS_NAME = "EDIT";
using namespace std;


LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, 
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
/*
 * Initialize the window class and register it.
 */
BOOL initInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance);
/*
 * Create and show the window
 */
HWND initWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance);

HWND createTextArea(HWND hParent);
/*
 * 
 */
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hprevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdline, INT cmdlShow)    
{
    if (!initInstance(hInstance)) 
        return 0;
    HWND hwndMain = initWindow(hInstance);
    ShowWindow(hwndMain, cmdlShow);
    MSG msg = {} ;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
BOOL initInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance) 
{   
    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance,
    wc.lpszClassName = MAINWINDOW_CLASS_NAME;

    return RegisterClass(&wc);
}
HWND initWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
   HWND hwndMain =  CreateWindow(
            MAINWINDOW_CLASS_NAME, // The class name
            "Text Editor", // The window name
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,// The window style
            CW_USEDEFAULT, // The x pos
            CW_USEDEFAULT, // The y pos
            CW_USEDEFAULT, // The width
            CW_USEDEFAULT, // The height
            (HWND) NULL, // Handle to parent
            (HMENU) NULL, // Handle to the menu
            hInstance, // Handle to the instance
            NULL        // Window creation data
            );

   if (!hwndMain) {
       return NULL;
   }
   else {
       return hwndMain;
   }


}
 LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, 
                          WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
      HWND htextArea;
      char sztestText[] = "I should be able to see this text.";

     switch (uMsg) {
         case WM_CREATE:
             htextArea = createTextArea(hwnd);
             SendMessage(htextArea, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) sztestText);
             break;
         case WM_PAINT:   
             break;
         case WM_CLOSE:
             break;
         case WM_SIZE:
             RECT rectMainWindow;
             GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rectMainWindow);
             INT x = rectMainWindow.right - rectMainWindow.left + 50;   
             INT y = rectMainWindow.bottom - rectMainWindow.top + 50;

             MoveWindow(htextArea, 0, 0, x, y, TRUE);
     }

     return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
 }

 /*******************************************************************/
 HWND createTextArea(HWND hParent) {
     return CreateWindow(
             TEXTAREA_CLASS_NAME, // Class control name
             NULL,          // Title 
             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE, // Styles
             0, 0, 0, 0, // Sizing and position
             hParent,
             (HMENU) MAKEINTRESOURCE(100),
             (HINSTANCE) GetWindowLong(hParent, GWL_HINSTANCE),
             NULL       
             );
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `htextArea` as a local variable in `WinProc` and so every time your window procedure is called its value will be uninitialized. You should make it `static` or move it to global data outside the function.

(The actual problem is that when you get a `WM_SIZE` message, you've lost the handle to the edit control, and so its size remains as 0,0).

Comment: Thanks. The whole message system I have not yet wrapped my head around. I really should study that more.